# Keep synced folders/data online if unsynced

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

Hiya, I just unsynced one of my folders but had hoped the data would remain in the cloud until deleted - which is, quite obviuosly, not the case. So right now I'm trying to sync the whole folder again but I'm curious ***if there is a way of keeping the data online although I deactivate the sync option on my Netbook*** / Ubuntu 10.10. I tried to find information on this in the FAQ but couldn't... I'm thankful for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is to *unsubscribe* the local machine from the web folder, rather than *deleting* the web folder which is what Nautilus exports. If you're on Natty you can access this functionality via the Ubuntu One Control Panel:

[image: the Ubuntu One Control Panel “Cloud Folders” tab]

If you're not on Natty yet, you can get the folder id from `u1sdtool --list-folders`, and then use `u1sdtool --unsubscribe-folder=folder-id`.